# Reformat damaged Card

Tags: external-sd

My SD card is damaged and a message occurs "SD card is damaged. Try reformating it" what should I do?

Moto E
Android-4.4.4
SD card-kingston 16 GB (class 10)

Comment: Have you tried formatting it? If so, what happened?

Comment: I would buy a new SD card. You could run scandisk on it, or try to reformat it with gparted or similar, but if there is physical damage it's done. They have a limited life of read-writes.

Answer (score 1):

Before using atomics, I'd try to attach the card to a PC with a card reader, and use the PC's tools to ***check and repair*** (i.e. `fsck` on *nix systems, or the corresponding tool on Windows – I'm using Linux, so I'm not familiar with the Windows part: [chkdsk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK)? [ScanDisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_ScanDisk)?)

Most likely you've "unsafely removed" the card (e.g. plugged it out from your computer before having it "unmounted"), which left the file system corrupted (not being closed properly). Using `fsck`/`chkdsk` and similar tools, you might be able to "recover" without any (or with just minimal) data loss.

If however this occurs regularly without you having either "unsafely removed" the card (or [hard-reset](/questions/tagged/hard-reset) your device, cutting it off from power without having safely shut down), there might be an incompatibility between your card and your device (such are reported from time to time). In that case, it's rather adviced you by a new card of a different brand/size/specification and see if that's running more stable.

Please also see our [external-sd tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/external-sd/info), which even has a nice and easy-to-follow graphic for how to deal with SD card issues (congrats to me for that :)